# Recently publicized modern C derivative?

Tags: c++, c

I remember reading in Hacker News about a modern C-like language with pretty nifty features, but I can't find it again. The name I can evoke is "C9", but that's not yielding search results.

It was pretty much a superset of C, with multi-pass compilation (and thus, no need for headers and forward declarations) and namespaces, as well as dynamic array syntax and string handling sugar.

I'm about to embark in a low-level project, and this would be a fantastic opportunity to try it out. My C is a bit rusty, I'm afraid, after years of python and coffeescript, so it would surely come in very handy.

Any hope somebody in SO has heard about it, or a similar project?

Comment: You mean C99? Or maybe Go? Anyway, why not just use C++? It’s for all intense porpoises a modern C replacement (at least on platforms where it’s supported) that works well with low-level code.

Comment: Haha no, not at all. I'm familiar with recent C standards, and have given Go a try. This was something much less famous. I learned to stay away from C++ after numerous headaches, but thank you for the suggestions!

Comment: I think you'll find SO chat more suitable for playing a game of "guess this programming language."

Comment: How could you possibly have more headaches with C++ than with C? It might be a biased opinion, but I can't comprehend.

Comment: C is easy to understand. If I shoot myself in the foot, I can at least figure out why I was aiming for it. C++ is too much of a complicated beast for my taste :(

Comment: Perhaps you should look at Rust. It's a systems programming language like C, though it is not a superset of C.

Comment: @KonradRudolph C++ is *too hard* for me. I'm a lazy coder - and C++ is freaking *complicated* :D

Comment: @pst Well it’s complicated to learn, I give you that. But it makes writing complex programs correctly easier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I read the same article.  It sounds like [C2](http://www.c2lang.org/), including the multi-pass parsing.

Comment: INDEED! THANKS! And double thanks for actually answering and not dismissing the question

Comment: @MichaelBurr The infamous off-by-seven error